# Extra Space Inserted After Consecutive Floating Environments

Tags: spacing, floats

When putting two floating environments consecutively inside a paragraph as in the example below, TeX seems to insert an additional space after the last floating environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
There is an additional space before this
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{B}
\end{figure}% <--- gets rid of extra space
word.
\end{document}
```

[image: Extra Space]

Adding `%` after the last figure, gets rid of the extra space.

[image: No Extra Space]

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Adding floats mid paragraph is possible, but I can't recommend it.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment! I have always thought floats should be put immediately after the text reference. Let‘s say the paragraph is very long and the two floats are referenced near the beginning. Should I then put the floats after the end of the paragraph?

Comment: The chance that floats will fall at the desired spot is very little. Two in a row even less.

Comment: @egreg So, if I understand correctly, floats should be put before/after a paragraph?

Comment: Yes, between paragraphs is the best choice, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much! Do you recommend before or after the paragraph? Or does it depend on where in the paragraph the floats are referenced?

Comment: Why you use two floats? Does just one with both images and captions does not meet your expectations?

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, for not being clear about this. Actually, the first figure is a table containing data connected to a plot in the second figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two causes of the additional inter-word space between "this" and "word".

- The first cause is the absence of `%`, i.e., a comment character, at the end the input line `There is an additional space before this`.
- The second cause is the absence of `%` at the end of both `\end{figure}` lines.

Supplying a `%` character at the end of the first or third possible location suffices to generate a normal inter-word space. Inserting a `%` character at the end of all 3 lines gets rid of the inter-word space altogether.

---

*Addendum* to summarize some of the thoughts contained in the comments:

- In a way, it is your coding choice that needlessly causes the complications (such as extra whitespace), which you then find necessary to fix. IMNSHO, there is no discernible advantage to inputting the floats as

  ```
  There is an additional space before this
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{B}
  \end{figure}
  word.
  ```

  Instead, as @egreg has already suggested, just enter the material as

  ```
  There is an additional space before this word.
  \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \caption{B}
  \end{figure}
  ```

  if the objective is to keep the floats close to the text that precedes them.
- As @DavidCarlisle has explained in the comments below, the extra inter-word whitespace isn't really the result of LaTeX wantonly putting it there; indeed, it's *your* oddball coding choice that's creating the extra whitespace issue. While TeX and LaTeX will successfully discard *consecutive* extra whitespace of the type `word   word`, they weren't set up to ferret out and eliminate needless whitespace of the type `word {}  () word`, where `{}` forms an empty group.
- The upshot: Either get into the habit of adding `%` after each instance of `\end{figure}`, or start coding more sensibly so that the whitespace issue discussed in this posting never even arises.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But why I do not need to add a `%` character if there is only one figure?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria - I'm not entirely sure. Hopefully, somebody else will post an answer that addresses your follow-up question as well.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria latex goes to some effort to check whether a space appears before or after a figure and just produce one space in either case. However you have space-figure-space-figure-space  and it only manages to detect that it needs to remove one. Arguably it ought to try harder but it's always been this way and changing it might have compatibility issues

Comment: note that you never have to add `%` you could not add space instead `this\begin{figure}..\end{figure}\begin{figure} ..\end{figure} word` would only have one space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, this makes perfect sense! But why does LaTeX in the first place insert an extra space? Normally, consecutive spaces in the source are disregarded.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria hey latex didn't insert space, latex just failed to remove it after you added it :-)  consecutive spaces are only combined if they really are consecutive compare `one--two` and `one-{}-two`  or in your case `one-{}-{}-two`  (where `-` is marking a space)  you see even `{}` is enough to stop space combining and you have a lot more than that. an entire figure environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, ok, now I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mico If you could add the additional information by David, I will be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria - Done.

Comment: @Mico Thank you!

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria - I hope my language in the addendum wasn't too forceful.,

Comment: @Mico No, it‘s fine.